# Is it possible for multiple developers to run their tests on one Appium server or on the same real iOS device?

Tags: appium

I have Appium installed and set up on a Mac with the latest version Ventura 13.2. I can already run tests on an iOS real device, but I would like to run tests or access the device from another Mac on the same iOS device. I couldn't find any information about this but I think Appium must be running on a Public IP (Maybe!). Does anyone have experience with this and can help me?

I tried to run Appium Server on a public IP but it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I continued testing there. It would go that the other developers also access the same iOS device but this then breaks the first session! That is, the device can not logically be used at the same time by multiple developers.